# Word 2011 - Utilize full page width

Tags: microsoft-word

When I create a new word document in Word 2011 (Print Layout), by default I can see that on both the sides (left and right), there is a wide gray area.

I can use the page margin rulers to increase page width within the given bounds. However, how do I increase the width of the page itself to reduce the gray surrounding area? Below is the screenshot:

[image: Page Width in Microsoft Word Mac 2011]

I can increase the page size by using the zoom option. However, I don't want to zoom in but increase the page width itself.

On my other machine, in MS Word 2007, by default for a new word document in print layout I get a better layout (more page width and lesser surrounding gray area).

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the page size by going to the `Page Layout` tab and choosing a different page size under the `Size` drop down list. I'm not entirely sure this is what you really want though, why not just select `Page Width` under zoom so you can see the whole page without the grey bars?

Answer (score 0):

Use the View > Zoom > Page Width option from the menu.